# Proving that $\chi(Q_n) = n$ where $n$ is the Queen's graph and $\gcd(n, 6) = 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, discrete-optimization

Let $Q_n$ be the Queen's graph with $n^2$ vertices. I was asked to show that $\chi(Q_n) = n$ whenever $6$ and $n$ are coprime. I have failed to provide a coloring that proves this for the general case.

It is straightforward to see that any diagonal, column or row in the "board" is a $K_n$ graph, and therefore $\chi(Q_n) \geq n$. But I cannot see how the fact that $n$ is coprime with $6$ restricts the optimal coloring to $n$.

I'd appreciate any hint or answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find a solution where lines, columns, and diagonals are in arithmetic progression (modulo $n$).

Comment: There is an $n$-coloring in many cases where $\gcd(n,6)>1$, too. The reason to look at case where $\gcd(n,6)=1$ is that in this case, a simple construction (found by Pólya in 1918, I believe) is known. Some other known values of $\chi(Q_n)$ are given in OEIS [A088202](https://oeis.org/A088202), and for all we know, $\chi(Q_n) = n$ for all $n\ge 11$, but this is open.